# Dygraphs vertical line with label

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I need to place a vertical line with a label on my dygraph like the National holiday line in this example - http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-attributes.html?chart=msline

I have searched google for about 2 hours and can't find any examples. Can someone shoot me an example or put me on the right track?  Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to do a foreach through the points on drawCallback?  I can draw the line like I want but it is on the highlightCallback.  So what I want to do is look through all of the points until I find the one that I want to draw a line at and then add my line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dygraph vertical line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353539/dygraph-vertical-line)

Answer (score 2):

Best practice today is to add highlighted region using [underlay callback](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#underlayCallback) ([example](http://dygraphs.com/tests/highlighted-region.html)).

try specifying the "underlayCallback" option within your "new Dygraph()" call. Use HTML Canvas context to draw the line.

On creating your graph:

```
// Graph range on X axis:
var xMin=0, xMax=1;
// horizontal line Y value:
var yValue = 0.5;

new Dygraph(document.getElementById('garph'), data, {
    // Graph options
    underlayCallback: function(ctx, area, dygraph) {
        var xLeft =  dygraph.toDomCoords(Min, yValue);
        var xRight = dygraph.toDomCoords(Max, yValue);
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(xLeft[0],  xLeft[1] );
        ctx.lineTo(xRight[0], xRight[1]);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
    }
});
```

Note this is a very general example, as you haven't shown your own code.